# Search query not working when using a date variable (does when hard-coded) in Internet Explorer

Tags: search, spfx, internet-explorer, pnp, pnp-js-core

**Issue**

In my SPFx app I am using search to pull back events.  Everything is working great, except in IE and Edge.  I have determined what it doesn't like, but not why it doesn't like it.

**Rendered Search Query:**

`contenttype:Event CompanyEventDate=7/1/2018..9/30/2018`

Instead of hard-coding this and having to update every month, I have methods that calculate last month's start date and next month's end date.

So my actual line of code looks like this **(This does not work in IE or Edge)**:

```
return SearchQueryBuilder.create(`${this.props.searchQuery} CompanyEventDate=${this._getMonthStartSearchQueryDate(startMonth)}..${this._getMonthEndSearchQueryDate(endMonth)}`, searchQuerySettings);
```

If I replace my methods with hard-coded dates..

**This does work in IE and Edge:**

```
return SearchQueryBuilder.create(`${this.props.searchQuery} CompanyEventDate=7/1/2018..9/30/2018`, searchQuerySettings);
```

Both are returning, what looks to be, the same querytext.  I don't know what the difference is that IE and Edge are seeing.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

**Additional Notes**

- I have tried formatting the date differently (using hyphens, 2-digit months and dates).  I get the same results (works when hard-coded, but not when returned from method).
- I am following the network calls in Chrome and IE Dev Tools, and the requests are identical when comparing them in Notepad.

Comment: Can you also post the snippet of SearchQueryBuilder.create function? The issue could be inside that function

Comment: @GautamSheth That is a part of the PnP-JS-Core library.  https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Search

Comment: ok, can you post the `_getMonthStartSearchQueryDate` method ? Try logging the value of `${this._getMonthStartSearchQueryDate(startMonth)}` in console and check if its correct